# Calculating Summing value from object based on array and updating same with total

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping

I have an object with basically three important parameters I need to for total calculation.
So for example my object is as below :

```
[
{'Id':1,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':8,'TotalHrs':8},
{'Id':2,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4},
{'Id':3,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4},
{'Id':4,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4},
{'Id':5,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':2,'TotalHrs':2},
{'Id':6,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4},
{'Id':7,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':2,'TotalHrs':2},
]
```

So, currently the TotalHrs parameter is of the same value as the Hours parameter.

I want it to be total for a particular ResourceId and Startdate.
i.e If in the array if the ResourceId and Startdate matches the TotalHrs parameter should be total of the value from Hours parameter.

So the final array becomes.

```
[
{'Id':1,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':8,'TotalHrs':12},
{'Id':2,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':12},
{'Id':3,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':8},
{'Id':4,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':8},
{'Id':5,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':2,'TotalHrs':6},
{'Id':6,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':6},
{'Id':7,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':2,'TotalHrs':2},
]
```

Hence in the above example, `ResourceId` : 1 and `StartDate` : 01-01-2017 has two occurrences with Hours value as 8 and 4, so there TotalHrs becomes 8+4=12.

Also, I don't want to group by, I want the same number of elements in the resulting array but with an updated value for `TotalHrs`.

Comment: values like `'StartDate'='01-01-2017'` are invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a javascript array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, its not the date format exactly, its the String.I do need to use it this way for the sake of application.

Comment: @Mukta, do you want to obtain a  new array or to modify the initial array in place?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I want to modify the initial array.

Comment: @Mukta, ok, you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) functions:

```js
var data = [ {'Id':1,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':8,'TotalHrs':8}, {'Id':2,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4}, {'Id':3,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4}, {'Id':4,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4}, {'Id':5,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':2,'TotalHrs':2}, {'Id':6,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4,'TotalHrs':4}, {'Id':7,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':2,'TotalHrs':2} ];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    o.TotalHrs = this[o.ResourceId + o.StartDate];
}, data.reduce(function (r, o) {
    var k = o.ResourceId + o.StartDate;
    (!r[k])? r[k] = o.TotalHrs : r[k] += o.TotalHrs;
    return r;
}, {}));

console.log(data);
```

`var k = o.ResourceId + o.StartDate;` - `k` here is a *hash key string* for grouping entries with same `ResourceId` and `StartDate` attributes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a temporary object, using the `StartDate` and `ResourceId` as hash key, that will store the hours. This algorithm providers O(n) time complexity.

```js
var data = [{'Id':1,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':8},{'Id':2,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4},{'Id':3,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4},{'Id':4,'ResourceId':1,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':4},{'Id':5,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':2},{'Id':6,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-01-2017','Hours':4},{'Id':7,'ResourceId':2,'StartDate':'01-03-2017','Hours':2}];

function populateTotalHrs(collection) {
  var collectionByHash = {};
  collection.forEach(function(obj) {
    var hash = obj.ResourceId + '_' + obj.StartDate;
    collectionByHash[hash] = collectionByHash[hash] || 0;
    collectionByHash[hash] += obj.Hours;
  });
  collection.forEach(function(obj) {
    var hash = obj.ResourceId + '_' + obj.StartDate;
    obj.TotalHrs = collectionByHash[hash];
  });  
}

populateTotalHrs(data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and group it temporary by `ResourceId` and `StartDate`.

```js
var data = [{ Id: 1, ResourceId: 1, StartDate: '01-01-2017', Hours: 8, TotalHrs: 8 }, { Id: 2, ResourceId: 1, StartDate: '01-01-2017', Hours: 4, TotalHrs: 4 }, { Id: 3, ResourceId: 1, StartDate: '01-03-2017', Hours: 4, TotalHrs: 4 }, { Id: 4, ResourceId: 1, StartDate: '01-03-2017', Hours: 4, TotalHrs: 4 }, { Id: 5, ResourceId: 2, StartDate: '01-01-2017', Hours: 2, TotalHrs: 2 }, { Id: 6, ResourceId: 2, StartDate: '01-01-2017', Hours: 4, TotalHrs: 4 }, { Id: 7, ResourceId: 2, StartDate: '01-03-2017', Hours: 2, TotalHrs: 2 }];

data.forEach(function (hash) {
    return function (a) {
        var key = [a.ResourceId, a.StartDate].join('|');
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = [a];
            return;
        }
        hash[key].push(a);
        hash[key][0].TotalHrs += a.Hours;
        hash[key].forEach(function (b) {
            b.TotalHrs = hash[key][0].TotalHrs;
        });
    };
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```